# Tamanho máximo do app_name para evitar reticências

Tags: android, google-play

Qual é o tamanho máximo (*max length*) para a string **app_name** do arquivo `strings.xml` do projeto em *Android* para evitar esta problemática ?

Por exemplo o nome **My butterfly** tem `length = 12` (contando o espaço) e não contém reticências em seu nome. Já o nome **Meus cartões** tem o mesmo tamanho, `length = 12` (contando o espaço), e apresenta esta problemática.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Será que o motivo de "estourar" seria por causa de caracteres acentuados? Já me aconteceu de internamente esses caracteres serem convertidos para outros que acabava "confundindo" os interpretadores...

Comment: Mudei por curiosidade, e deu no mesmo. Acredito que tenha algo a ver com a largura de cada letra em sí.. por exemplo a letra i e w tem larguras diferentes. Mas não sei se há algum padrão.

Comment: Ah sim, agora eu percebi a sua questão... Me desculpe por ter interpretado equivocadamente. Sim, isso faz todo sentido, já que, aparentemente, seria como se cada caractere fosse uma "imagem" com a largura da própria letra. Talvez você pudesse retirar o espaço ficando "MeusCartões" para ver se fica melhor, ou deixar apenas "Cartões".

Comment: Fiz isso... coloquei apenas Cartões mesmo, apesar de o nome do aplicativo na Google Play Store ser outro : [Confira aqui](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev.marcellocamara.pgm). Acredito que esta problemática não tenha solução e sim boas práticas de uso... Mas valeu !